# Having Issues connecting to MySQL Database build from Docker Image with Python (PyMySQL/SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I have a Docker Image that builds a MySQL Database from a SQL text file based on a docker-compose.yml file

I've added on to the script with python command to run a python script just once after the database is build. Below is the code for the docker-compose.yml file

docker-compose.yml:

```
   version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: db
    # env_file: _docker/.env
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - ./dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE  # CAP_SYS_NICE
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "host.docker.internal"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
  #python script to run the file
  python:
    build: ./    
    command: python deconstructer.py
    depends_on:
     - db
```

I also do have a dockerfile that does the installation of python + the dependences used by the python script below

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./pipeline/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./pipeline/ /app/
```

This is the current DB configuration I'm using in my python scripts:

```
conn = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:admin@db:3306/dbname')
```

The Database builds perfectly fine, However I am running into this error in my terminal when trying to execute the python script with docker.

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

I am able to run the python file independently and it communicates just fine with the Database however its when I try to execute it with docker, the issue arises.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your application is connecting to localhost (127.0.0.1) instead of to DB container

Comment: @Facty I am pointing it to the DB container with this connection string: create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:admin@db:3306/dbname')

Is there another way that I'm missing out on?

Comment: but your python application log telling different `"Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'"` can you please doublecheck?

Comment: Presumably the scripts in ./dumps do in fact build a database called `dbname` (or whatever you substituted that for)? I don't think the connection string is obviously wrong. Actually because you bound the 3306 port to localhost, connecting to 127.0.0.1:3306 should work just as well as db:3306 (so I'm not sure that's the problem, @Facty ).

Comment: That is wrong assumption because you are connecting from container `python` to container `db`. From python script point of view `localhost` is container `python` which is not listening on 3306.